# Error installing gulp using nodejs on windows

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am getting the following error while installing gulp using nodejs on my windows OS. The following is the error I get when I type:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

This is the output I get:

```
npm ERR! v8flags@1.0.1 install: `node fetch.js` 
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT 
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the v8flags@1.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the v8flags package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node fetch.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8flags
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "E:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "gulp"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\pramod\Desktop
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `npm --loglevel=silly install -g gulp` somewhere?

Comment: @mscdex: Yes I did run the command, but the logs are too big, Can you send me your email so I can mail you the log?

https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/ff53dc96c7cf9422f00a1cb8672804a420141102145042/fe3edd2ecc104cd167b4522573a0b2f620141102145042/1b697f

Comment: I have tried to upload it on wetransfer and have sent you the link.. let me know if you can download it

Comment: Is your `PATH` environment variable set up properly (since it seems like your `Users` and `Program Files` directories are on different drives)? What does `where node` output when you execute it from a command prompt?

Comment: Can you also post the output of "npm install -g gulp -verbose"?

Comment: Yes, back then I was trying to uninstall and perhaps install it on my E: drive. I did install it back in the default C: drive but its still not working. Please find the link contain the verbose details.

https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/5ff7d6f50f3e7e568af60710533fa72320141103121920/b0924747b00c68c3e6ef0d594f0a85b620141103121920/5beea5

Comment: Hi I have some new updates..
I uninstall the latest nodejs - node-v0.10.33-x64 and
I installed a prev version of nodejs - node-v0.10.29-x64

I then ran npm install gulp / npm install -g gulp and I donot get any errors.

Comment: However, now if I enter gulp - it says its not recognized as a internal/external command. I even tried setting the the NODE_JS environment variable on both my User/System environment but still getting the error. :(